# How can I get data from a POST request in Perl?

Tags: perl, web, server, cgi

I have a Perl script that runs and acts like a web page, on it I have create a from like this.

```
sub displayFrom{
my $html;
$html.= getHeader(add User);
$html.= getNavBar();
$html .= '<form method ="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">';
$html .= '<input type="text" id="username" name="username">';
$html .= '<input type="password" id="password" name="password">';
$html .= '<input type="submit" id="btn_submit" name="btn_submit">';
$html .= '</from>';
print $html;
}
```

Then in my dispatcher I have this.

```
sub dispatch{
my $createRequest = $CGI->param("btn_submit");
if(defined $createRequest){
    print Dumper $CGI;
}
```

When I print the content of CGI, I cant see the field username and password. I am fairly new to Perl and Perl web/server stuff. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your form has no `action`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `$CGI->param("btn_submit");` it will only work corresponding to btn_submit.

If you need to find the username and password, try this

```
my $username = $CGI->param("username");
my $password = $CGI->param("password");
```

Comment: I tried that, but the $CGI->param does noot contain a key for "username" and "password", so I get empty strings